# Phase portrait of $y_2 = y_{20}*exp(\lambda*t)$ $y_1 = y_{10}*exp(\lambda*t)+ y_{20}*t*exp(\lambda*t)$

Tags: geometry, matlab, parametric, nonlinear-system

$y_2 = y_{20}*exp(\lambda*t)$

$y_1 = y_{10}*exp(\lambda*t)+ y_{20}*t*exp(\lambda*t)$

I am struggling to reproduce the diagram corresponding to the equations above.

I have tried to code it in matlab but am unable to do so successfully. Can someone please explain where my code is wrong

[image]

thank you

Comment: Looks like you’re getting the correct shapes. Try different values for the two constants.

Comment: @amd but i cant get the curves to intersect the axis

Answer (score 1):

You weren't very far from your objective. You hadn't "nice looking" results because you chose $\lambda >0$ giving divergent curves instead of convergent curves (converging to $0$).

Here is a convenient code :

```
clear all;close all;hold on;
L=-1;% lambda
t=0:0.1:5;
a=-1;
for b=0:0.2:2 
    plot(a,b,'ob');
    plot((a+b*t).*exp(L*t),b.*exp(L*t),'b');
end;
a=1;
for b=-2:0.2:0 
    plot(a,b,'or');
    plot((a+b*t).*exp(L*t),b.*exp(L*t),'r');
end;
```

giving the following figure :

[image]

The two families of curves have initial points (a,b) represented by little round shapes, with either $a=-1$ or $a=1$.

Reminder : we are in a case where

$$\binom{x}{y}=\exp(tA)\binom{a}{b}$$

with $$A:=\begin{pmatrix}L&1\\0&L\end{pmatrix} \ \ \implies \ \ \exp(tA)=\begin{pmatrix}\exp(Lt)&t \exp(Lt)\\0&\exp(Lt)\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Hi thanks, but when comparing you curve to the one in the photo, it doesn’t look the same. The curves dont seem to intersect the “x axis” , it looks more like the photo when you rotate the graph 90degrees clockwise. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Don't consider the orientation as a "sacred" one. Take a look for example to http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/PhasePlane.aspx in the case "improper node Asymptol. stable" : you will see that its axis (blue line) is neither the $x$ nor the $y$ axis... If you desire the orientation as in your drawing, just interchange in each plot the $x$ and the $y$...

Comment: thanks mate, got it now!